# Different answer counts if there are deleted answers

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, deleted-answers, android-app

At the left (site), it says 3 Answers (1 Accepted Answer + 2 self-deleted-answer). At the right (app), it says only 1 Answer; self-deleted answers are not visible.

[image]

Comment: I would say the issue is not only for self-deleted answers but also for deleted answers (which can be viewed by 10K+ users.)

Comment: @hims056 Thanks. Rephrased the title.

Answer (score 6):

At this time we'll be supporting what is available through our public API - which is only content that has not been deleted.  It's possible we may change this later to support > 10K users however this will not be in V1.0

Comment: Any plan for improvising the api to show deleted questions/answers in android app for 10K users?

Comment: Please make the change.  Even just filling the space with "This question/answer has been deleted." without displaying the content of the post is better than popping an alert.