# The Android App does not show deleted answers

Tags: bug, android-app

The Android App does not show any deleted answers at all, even on sites where I am a moderator. I just got a notification about a new meta post, the post is about a deleted answer, but when I follow the link to the answer the app pretends that there are no answers at all on that question.

Comment: The API does not show deleted answers. Nor deleted questions. The iOS app suffers from the same problem.

Comment: Here's Geoff's answer on what @MartijnPieters said, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192217/different-answer-counts-if-there-are-deleted-answers/192385#192385.

Comment: One alternative might be for it to automatically open the page in the browser instead?